# Change color of warning panel in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Could you help me out to change color of warning panel in PhpStorm ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "warning panel" -- it's a "notification panel".

Anyway: try this one -- this is the best matching style I could find:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`
3. `Editor | Notification Background` styling element.